# Git merging a file, actually trying to re-do the merge for one file

Tags: git

I am merging a branch to my upstream branch. You can consider it to be just a merge between two branches. Now, after I took care of all the merge conflicts manually, I did a fresh build and found that one of the source files has compilation errors.

To solve this, I wanted to re-do the merge for this file with errors without doing it for the rest of the files I already merged. So, is there a way to fix this without taking the pain of doing it from scratch.

To explain it better, assume three files A, B and C are present in the upstream. I run git pull to get the content from remote branch to be merged with these. Now, I see merge conflicts and I resolve these manually, file by file. On doing compilation, I see file A and C compile fine whereas B has errors. So, now I want to re-merge B from start without wasting the effort I put in merging A and C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you haven't committed it yet, you can just check out the unmerged version of the file:

```
git checkout --merge path/to/file
```

Then you can re-resolve the conflict as you like. (`-m` is a synonym for `--merge`.)

Comment: I get an error when I try this, the error is "file does not have all three versions'

Comment: @GauravSinha: Is the merge still uncommitted, and did the file have a normal modify/modify conflict? Or was it created separately in two branches, or deleted in one of them, or renamed, or anything like that?

Comment: yes, the merge is not committed. This is a normal modify/modify conflict, but the number of conflicts is high.

Comment: Hm. I've used this plenty, and just retested it just in case. It worked fine. The three versions that are referred to are the common ancestor, and the "ours" and "theirs" branches. I'm not sure what could have gone wrong for you. (Double-check, just in case - maybe clone the repo and redo the merge there, and make sure that this file truly does have a modify/modify conflict, with a common ancestor.)

Comment: yes, I think something went wrong after I tried a lot of things in this directory, un-staged / staged the file a couple of times. I am taking a backup of the entire source and will re-do the merge for the file which didn't compile and finally copy the files that did compile to this directory. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You can run `git merge-file`, which does a 3-way merge. If `HEAD` is the merge you just did, something like the following should work:

```
git cat-file blob HEAD^:fileB > fileB # revert fileB to its pre-merge condition
git cat-file blob $(git merge-base HEAD^ HEAD^2):fileB > fileB.base # write the base version to fileB.base
git cat-file blob HEAD^2:fileB > fileB.other # write the other version of fileB
git merge-file fileB fileB.base fileB.other
```

This will re-run the merge and write the merge results (including conflicts) back into `fileB` (at which point you can delete `fileB.base` and `fileB.other`).

**Edit:**

If you haven't actually ran `git add fileB` yet (e.g. if `git status` shows the merge conflict), and if you have the `git-merge-one-file` script on your disk (in my case it's sitting at `/usr/libexec/git-core/git-merge-one-file`), then you can run `git merge-index /path/to/git-merge-one-file fileB` and it will re-merge that file for you.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the merge resulted in the solution not ending up in a good state. Just edit the files you need to change so everything compiles and all your tests pass. If you want certain files to be pulled off of a state just before the merge,

```
git checkout origin/branch_you_want -- fileA fileB
```

Now just amend your merge commit:

```
git add -A
git commit --amend -C HEAD
```

This will reuse the same message. You should see your merge commit in a good state now.

UPDATE:

**WARNING! When doing merges and using --amend, you may have recorded a conflict resolution you did not intend! See rerere: http://progit.org/2010/03/08/rerere.html**

Comment: I haven't committed it yet. Also, the file had lots of merge conflicts, which are difficult to resolve manually without git putting in HEADs and ==== to quickly get to it. If I can get the merge to run for only this file, then this would make my life easier.

Comment: I see the discussion has helped you out. I just wanted to add this discraimer to my answer. Watch what you record for rerere when monkeying with merges after the fact :)